# Limit selection input field to 0, 3, 5, and 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to increase/decrease a quantity by whole numbers (except 0), multiply  this quantity by a given price, add a value to the total by a checkbox, and output it all as a total. So far, so good.

My current challenge is to limit the increments/decrements to 0,3,5,8.

I think I will have to alter  the following part (or leave it out altogether again) to account for 0s, but hit a wall for the rest:

```html
else {

        if (currentNb > 1) {
            newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) - 1;
        } else {
            newNb = 1;
            button.addClass('inactive');
        }
```

This is the code I have so far:

```js
var _EXTRAVAL = 1;

$(".incr-btn_mobile").on("click", function(e) {
  // Prevent default action
  e.preventDefault();

  // Set variable for the method
  var button = $(this);
  var labelNb = button.parent().find('.quantity');
  var labelPrice = $("#" + button.attr('data-target'));
  var currentNb = button.parent().find('.quantity').val();
  var newNb = 0;

  // Remove 'inactive' class
  $('.incr-btn_mobile[data-action="decrease"]').removeClass('inactive');

  // Increase or decrease
  if (button.attr('data-action') == "increase") {
    newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) + 1;
  } else {

    if (currentNb > 1) {
      newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) - 1;
    } else {
      newNb = 1;
      button.addClass('inactive');
    }
  }


  var isExtra = $("#include").prop('checked') ? _EXTRAVAL : 0;
  $(labelNb).val(newNb);
  $(labelPrice).css('display', 'block').html("=  $" + String((((newNb) * 7.99) + (isExtra)).toFixed(2)));

});


$("#include").on('click', function() {
  // Set variable for method
  var checkbox = $(this);
  var labelPrice = $("#" + $(".incr-btn_mobile").attr('data-target'));
  var labelPriceFloat = parseFloat(labelPrice.html().substring(4));

  // If checkbox is check, increse price
  if (checkbox.prop('checked')) {
    labelPrice.html("=  $" + String((labelPriceFloat + _EXTRAVAL).toFixed(2)));
  } else {
    labelPrice.html("=  $" + String((labelPriceFloat - _EXTRAVAL).toFixed(2)));
  }
});
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.count-input_mobile {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.count-input_mobile input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #000 border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.count-input_mobile input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm {
  max-width: 125px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm input {
  height: 36px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg input {
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button_mobile {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  padding: 10.5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="checkbox_align_1" style="width:20px;height:20px;" type="checkbox" id="include" name='include' data-target="cleanse_drop_1" />


<div class="count-input_mobile space-bottom">
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="decrease" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">–</a>
  <input class="quantity" id="ShowButton_value_1" type="text" name="quantity" value="0" />
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="increase" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">+</a>
</div>

<div id="cleanse_drop_1">= $ 0.00</div>

<input type="button" class="button_mobile" value="Add" onclick="addToCart()">
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear what you mean by "My current challenge is to limit the increments/decrements to 0,3,5,8."  Does this mean you want the input to be a multiple of 0, 3, 5, or 8?

Comment: Who cares what you're able to do? What's your question?

Comment: right now you can hit e.g. the "+"-sign and it increases by 1 as often as you hit it e.g. 30 times would result in 30. You can only decrease down to 1 unit. I would like it to increase the input from 0 to 3 to 5 to 8 and stop increasing. Same logic should apply for decreasing the count.

Comment: Note that `toFixed()` returns a string, so there's no need to convert it to a string.

Comment: First of all, you should use a `button` or `input type="button"` for your + and - actions. You can style them to look exactly the same. Then it's easier to disable them (find out how in [jQuery disable a link](//stackoverflow.com/q/970388)).

Comment: Then, the rest is math...

Comment: "Then, the rest is math..." :DDD Best response, mate. Thanks for the button link, will read up on it. Wasn't aware that there was any upside to it.

Comment: I posted a solution that gets the job done for now. What are the big drawbacks to it? (would like to understand the preference to the buttons solution)

Answer (score 1):

Without having replaced the links with buttons yet, this code works for the code above:

```js
var _EXTRAVAL = 3;

$(".incr-btn_mobile").on("click", function(e) {
    // Prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Set variable for the method
    var button = $(this);
    var labelNb = button.parent().find('.quantity');
    var labelPrice = $("#" + button.attr('data-target'));
    var currentNb = button.parent().find('.quantity').val();
    var newNb = 0;

    // Remove 'inactive' class
    $('.incr-btn_mobile[data-action="decrease"]').removeClass('inactive');

    // Increase or decrease
    if (button.attr('data-action') == "increase") {
   if ((currentNb) >= 8 ){
   // nichts machen
   }else{
    if ((currentNb == 0)||(currentNb == 5)){
   newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) + 3;
    }else if((currentNb == 3)){
   newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) + 2;
    }
  
   }
        
    }
    
    if (button.attr('data-action') == "decrease") {
   if ((currentNb) <= 0 ){
   // nichts machen
   }else{
    if ((currentNb == 8)||(currentNb == 3)) {
   newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) - 3;
    }else if((currentNb == 5)){
   newNb = parseFloat(currentNb) - 2;
    }
  
   }
        
    } 


    var isExtra = $("#include").prop('checked') ? _EXTRAVAL : 0;
    $(labelNb).val(newNb);
    $(labelPrice).css('display', 'block').html("=  $" + String((((newNb) * 7.99) + (isExtra)).toFixed(2)));
    
});
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.count-input_mobile {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.count-input_mobile input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #000 border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.count-input_mobile input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.count-input_mobile .incr-btn_mobile:first-child {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 46%;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm {
  max-width: 125px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-sm input {
  height: 36px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.count-input_mobile.count-input-lg input {
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button_mobile {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: none;
  padding: 10.5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="checkbox_align_1" style="width:20px;height:20px;" type="checkbox" id="include" name='include' data-target="cleanse_drop_1" />


<div class="count-input_mobile space-bottom">
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="decrease" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">–</a>
  <input class="quantity" id="ShowButton_value_1" type="text" name="quantity" value="0" />
  <a class="incr-btn_mobile" data-action="increase" data-target="cleanse_drop_1" href="#">+</a>
</div>

<div id="cleanse_drop_1">= $ 0.00</div>

<input type="button" class="button_mobile" value="Add" onclick="addToCart()">
```